# How to detach/dissociate public IP of VM through SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python, azure-sdk-for-ruby

I am looking for a way to dissociate public IP addresses from my nic that is associated with a VM that is part of a scale set. There is ways to do it through the Azure portal and CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/remove-public-ip-address-vm). My question is that is there a way to do it through azure python or ruby SDK?

I have tried the`network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, nic.name, nic_params)` approach. However, I am not quite sure what to set for the nic_params field. Existing document indicate that the field is of the format:

```html
        nic_params = {
            'location': LOCATION,
            'ip_configurations':[{
                'name': ipconfig_name,
                'public_ip_address':ip_address_object,
                'subnet': {
                    'id': subnet_info.id
                }
            }]
        }
```

I tried to set `ip_configuration` to null, `public_ip_address` to null. Neither approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to simply set the public ip address to "null".

These links should help you:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/network?view=azure-python
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_11_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--network-interface-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-

I don't know python, but the code would probably start something like this:

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, 'your-subscription-id')

network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(resource_group_name, network_interface_name,
{
'ip_configurations': ...
}
)
```

Comment: I will need to ask you to provide more information. I have tried this approach. There is a lack of information on how the parameters field should look like when trying to set it to "null". I have also updated my question to things I have tried.

Comment: @user1655072  did you able to find the answer . i also want to detach and list down all detached IP.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late reply, but it may be useful for someone who spent a substantial amount of time on this issue like I did. The key part is that a new `interface` object has to be constructed with `ipconfig.public_ip_address` set to `None`.

```
# Authenticate and connect to Azure cloud API
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

network_interface_id = "/some/azure/resource/id/foo/bar"
resource_group_name = network_interface_id.split("/")[4]
network_interface_name = network_interface_id.split("/")[-1]

# Get network interface object by its ID
interface = network_client.network_interfaces.get(
                resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
                network_interface_name=network_interface_name)

# Update public IP address in the Primary configuration of ip_configurations array
new_ip_configurations = []
for ipconfig in interface.ip_configurations:
    if ipconfig.primary:
        ipconfig.public_ip_address = None
    new_ip_configurations.append(ipconfig)
interface.ip_configurations = new_ip_configurations

result = network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(
                resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
                network_interface_name=network_interface_name,
                parameters=interface
         ).result()
```